# How to express the contrasting "still others", as in "some people do X, others do Y, still others do Z"?

Tags: выражения

In English, you say "some ..., while others ...", when comparing just two groups of people. And when the third group is thrown into the mix, you add "still" or "yet" to "others":

> ***Some*** people do X, ***others*** do Y, ***still***/***yet*** ***others*** do Z.

The same construction applies to the German equivalent as well:

> ***Manche*** von uns {Some of us} ..., ***andere*** {others} ..., ***wieder andere*** {again others} ...

What is a commonly used phrase in Russian for the third group "still others"?

Answer (score 9):

In Russian you can say "одни", "другие", "третьи" and so on for some particular groups and "остальные" for "the rest". E.g. "одни пьют виски, другие текилу, третьи ром, а остальные - водку".

Comment: Hi. What if the third group is the last of the bunch?  "одни пьют виски, другие текилу, а остальные - водку"? And is it necessary to place a dash after "остальные"?

Comment: I'm not sure I'd agree. "The rest" implies that you have now created an exhaustive list of what people drink, while "still others" doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a word which would work exactly like English "yet" when used with *другие* in Russian.

Usually it's conveyed by using *кто* with each group, optionally replacing it with *а кто и* for the last one:

> Кому поп, кому попадья, а кому и попова дочка.
>
> Кто верит в Магомета, кто — в Аллаха, кто — в Исуса, кто ни во что не верит — даже в чёрта, назло всем.

Comment: What's your take on "Кто-то ..., кто-то ..., а кто-то ..."?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens: this would work too, especially with the past tense.

Answer (score 1):

In these Cornell's lyrics from Be Yourself I would translate each "someone" and "another" as "кто-то":

Someone falls to pieces sleeping all alone
Someone kills the pain
Spinning in the silence
She finally drifts away
Someone gets excited in a chapel yard
Catches a bouquet
Another lays a dozen
White roses on a grave

Someone finds salvation in everyone, another only pain
Someone tries to hide himself, down inside himself he prays
Someone swears his true love until the end of time, another runs away
Separate or united, healthy or insane

That being said, in most cases "одни", "другие" and "a кто-то [ещё]" will work.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with **ещё кто-то**:
[https://context.reverso.net/перевод/русский-английский/А+еще+кто-то](https://context.reverso.net/%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4/%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B9%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9/%D0%90+%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5+%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE)

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use некоторые multiple times, to be honest.

> Некоторые из нас пьют виски, некоторые пьют пиво, а некоторые пьют вино.